# Map a domain to another subdomain - Rackspace

Tags: domain-name-system, asp.net-mvc, rackspace

I am using a subdomain as a parameter to an ASP.NET MVC 4 application. It's working well.

Now I need to test my approach, so I have the application hosted on appharbor. It works well with subdomains here too. Our DNS registers are on Rackspace, but I have no control over it. Another guy is responsible for that.
So, myapp.apphb.com can be accessed through myapp.com. 
Also abc.myapp.com is working as expected. I use abc as a parameter.

So, now I want abc.com to be mapped in those Rackspace DNS registers to abc.myapp.com

Is this possible at all? Can you explain to us how to do that? Will I have some problems with it? Anything that I should be aware of?

Please have in mind that I am newbie when it comes to DNS. And no experience with Rackspace.

Thanks.

Comment: If "Another guy is responsible for that" then ask him to figure it out!

Comment: It was my idea for this kind of approach.
It's complicated to explain... 
Anyway, if you can answer me the questions, regardless who is responsible, it would be great. Those are my concerns :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a CNAME to point abc.com (or a sub-domain, wildcard or @ record of abc.com) to the host abc.myapp.com.

Or you could set up an A record for abc.com (or a sub-domain, wildcard or @ record of abc.com) to the IP address of the host abc.myapp.com.

Of course you have to make sure that the host abc.myapp.com will handle requests made to abc.com once it start receiving them.